# Want to remove illegal tags from mp3 file using Python

Tags: python, regex, string, mp3

How to acheive this in my mp3 files.

> Artist:www.xyz.com
>        ---->
>   Artist:
>  Artist:free
>   downloads,free music,xyzhi.com
>     ----> Artist:
>   Artist:Kurukuru Kan (Amma Na) -
>   www.musicxyx.com -  ® Danaa
>   collections ®
>       ----> Artist:
>   Kurukuru Kan (Amma Na)
>  Artist:
>   Nan Pogiren - -  ® Danna collections ®
>      ----> Artist:Nan
>   Pogiren

I have been using Mutagen to access ID3 tags. How to manipulate the strings in the tags to achieve the above?

Comment: How can you tell that `Kurukuru Kan` is a legal name while `free downloads` isn't?

Comment: I see no difference as strings, just wanted to be practical. Trying to remove useless tag values.

Comment: Please could provide an explicit table of the mappings you want to make?

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need a library to understand the MP3 format and allow you to edit the tags, maybe: http://id3-py.sourceforge.net/

Beyond that, you'll just need to work on the string replacements.

For the ones you specified (including weird space requirements):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
EXPECTED = {
'Artist:www.xyz.com':'Artist:',
'Artist:free downloads,free music,xyzhi.com':'Artist:',
'Artist:Kurukuru Kan (Amma Na) - www.musicxyx.com - ® Danaa collections ®':'Artist: Kurukuru Kan (Amma Na)',
'Artist: Nan Pogiren - - ® Danna collections ®':'Artist:Nan Pogiren'}

import re

def process(instr):
    assert instr.startswith("Artist:")
    mo = re.match(r"^(Artist:)( ?)(.*?) - .*$",instr)
    if mo:
        spc = mo.group(2)
        if spc == " ":
            spc = ""
        else:
            spc = " "

        return "Artist:"+spc+mo.group(3)
    return "Artist:"

for (instr,outstr) in EXPECTED.iteritems():
    print process(instr),outstr,process(instr) == outstr
    assert process(instr) == outstr
```

Comment: I have been using the Mutagen ID3 Python library, and I am able to get strings that don't have anything like Artist or Album attached to it. What change in the above script would enable me to do the exact thing above without 'Artist:' in the original and expected strings.

Comment: @Arun - why did you include Artist: in the examples then?